# PHP Xdebug Setup in Docker-Warden for Vs Code on MacOS

Tags: magento2, xdebug, adobe-commerce, vscode, macos

I'm currently working as an Adobe Commerce Cloud developer and have recently transitioned to MacOS. I've successfully set up my Adobe Commerce project in Docker using Warden and I'm using Vs Code as my primary IDE for development.

Now, I'm facing challenges in adding PHP Xdebug for my local setup. Despite following videos and official documents, I haven't been able to make it work. Additionally, I couldn't find official documentation specifically for PHP Xdebug setup in Docker-Warden for Vs Code (unlike PHPStorm, where such documentation is available) for the local environment, excluding integration, staging, or production.

If you have any recommended documentation links or resources for my specific requirements, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Your guidance will not only benefit me but also others facing a similar situation.

Thank you in advance for your help.